# Python Jupyter notebook how to display matrix in vertical

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, pytorch, display

When I try to index array, I use this code for printing column part with Numpy or Pytorch.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(5,3)
a[:,1]
```

or

```
import torch
a = torch.Tensor(5,3)
a[:,1]
```

The output is displayed like this.

```
array([-0.07478094, -1.87787326,  0.50407517,  1.13335836,  0.23140931])
```

But I want to display output as column.(because i indexed column)

```
array([-0.07478094,
       -1.87787326,
        0.50407517,
        1.13335836,
        0.23140931])
```

Furthermore, When I make tensor with torch.ones(5), the result is

```
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

but I want to see the type of output on the buttom like this

`tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
[torch.FloatTensor of size 5]`

The reason why i want to display this is that i can't distinguish tensor and numpy

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: try displaying `a[:, [1]]`.  The shape should then be (n,1)  and display as a column.

Comment: Hey @justin_sakong try the ans below

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
np.vstack(a)
```

**Hope this helps..**